# Show that $\{A_{\alpha}: \alpha\in I\}$ is a set using the axiom of replacement in ZFC

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm reading Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*.

Let $I$ be a set, and for every $\alpha\in I$, let $A_\alpha$ be a set. In order to apply the axiom schema of replacement to construct the set $\{A_{\alpha}: \alpha\in I\}$, we need a **formula** $φ(x,y)$（a formula is defined to be a string of symbles constructed from the atomic formulas $x\in y$ and $x=y$ by repeated applications of logical operators $\vee$, $\wedge$, etc). I know that we generally don't write out the formula itself (for the sake of convenience), but the fact of the matter is that we should be able to "translate" what we write into a legal formula.

For instance, if one wished to prove the existence of the collection $\{\mathscr{P}(x):x\in A\}$ of all power sets of members of $A$, one could use the "illegal" statement $P(x,y)：y=\mathscr{P}(x)$, which can be rewritten as a legal formula $φ(x,y):\forall t(t\in y\leftrightarrow (\forall u(u\in t \rightarrow u\in x)))$.

When constructing the set $\{A_{\alpha}: \alpha\in I\}$, the "illegal" statement we use is $P(\alpha,y): y=A_\alpha$. But I have no idea how I shoud rewrite this statement as a legal formula.

We can rewrite it first as $\forall t(t\in y\leftrightarrow t\in A_\alpha)$. But how can I rewrite "$t\in A_\alpha$" as a formula?

Here is an example of how $\alpha\mapsto A_\alpha$ might be defined:$I=\{1,2,3\}, A_1:=\{2,3\},A_2:=\{3,4\},A_3:=\{4,5\}$.

Sorry for the language barrier.

Comment: How is your $\alpha\mapsto A_\alpha$ defined, if not by a formula?

Comment: @AnneBauval, I have edited my question to give an example of how $\alpha\rightarrow A_\alpha$ might be defined. This is an example from Terence Tao's textbook. The sets $A_\alpha$ seem to be established by hand.

Comment: In your example, since $I$ is finite, it is easy to "rewrite $t\in A_\alpha$ as a formula". Do you have an example with $I$ infinite?

Comment: @AnneBauval I have no backgroud in mathematical logic. Could you tell me how can I rewrite "$t\in A_\alpha$" as a formula in that example?. For example, I know precisely how to rewrite "$t\in\mathscr{P}(A)$". It's just "$t\subseteq A$" or "$\forall x(x\in t\rightarrow x\in A)$". But the symbol $A_\alpha$ seems strange to me.

Comment: So does it to me. Whence my 1st comment. I think it cannot be defined in another way than by a formula (or some sentence playing the role of). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family

Comment: Sorry, I skipped the question in your last comment. Here is a formula for that example: $(\alpha=1\land(t=2\lor t=3))\lor(\alpha=2\land(t=3\lor t=4))\lor(\alpha=3\land(t=4\lor t=5)).$ My thought "it cannot be defined in another way..." concerned the general case, not that example.

Comment: @AnneBauval. Thanks for your comments. But I think the formula you write is "$(\exists\alpha\in I)t\in A_\alpha$", not "$t\in A_\alpha$".

Comment: No, it is not. The 2 variables in my formula are free.

Comment: @AnneBauval I still have difficulty understanding how you rewrite $t\in A_\alpha$ as a formula.  But now I know how to properly rewrite it in a different way. In fact, $A_\alpha$ in the example should be considered a function of $\alpha$ with $I\subseteq dom(A)$. Using one of the set-theoretic definition of functions which treat them as just sets of ordered pairs obeying the vertical line test, one can rewrite $t\in A_\alpha$ as $\forall a((\alpha,a)\in A\rightarrow t\in a$). (The part $(\alpha,a)\in A$ should be rewritten as well, which is rather simple).

Answer (score 4):

The point you're missing here is what does the statement "Let $I$ be a set and  for every $\alpha\in I$ let $A_\alpha$ be a set". There are two ways to read this statement.

1. The statement is saying that there is a function $A$ with domain $I$, such that $A(\alpha)$, denoted by $A_\alpha$ is also a set.

   In this case, $A$, being a function in the universe, is already a set, so it is enough to prove that if $F$ is a function $\operatorname{rng}(F)$ is a set. The way to prove this depends on the specific encoding of "function", but generally this will involve some kind of Separation axiom and possibly some unions.
2. The statement is saying that there is a definable property $\varphi(x,y)$ (possibly with parameters, which I will omit) which defines the function $A$ on the set $I$. In that case, either apply Replacement directly, or first prove that if $I$ is a set and $\varphi$ defines a function on $I$, then there is a set which equals that function, and then fallback to the previous case. (Note that the latter option will require you to first do the former, so in a sense it is full of redundancies here.)

Comment: (+1) That is exactly what my 3 first comments and my link meant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Terence Tao says in his blog that so long as $A_{\alpha}$ is a well-formed mathematical expression pertaining to an element $\alpha\in I$, the axiom of replacement may be used to construct the set $\{A_{\alpha} : \alpha\in I\}$. And this is in particular the case if $A_{\alpha}$ was defined as a function of $\alpha\in I$. Can you explain what "mathematical expression" precisely means? Does it mean that $A_{\alpha}$ is something of the form $\mathscr{P}(\alpha)$ or $\alpha\cup X$($X$ is some set here), etc?

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for your link. But unfortunately it's banned in my country. Now I assume that $A_\alpha$ is any well-formed mathematical expression pertaining to an element $\alpha\in I$. For instance, $A_\alpha$ could be $\mathscr{P}(\alpha)$, $\alpha\cup X$($X$ is an arbitrary set),$F[\alpha]$(the image of $\alpha$ under some function $F$), etc. In particular, $A_\alpha$ could be defined as a function of $\alpha\in I$. I don't know the precise meaning of a "mathematical expression", but I think maybe there is a specific definition of it in mathematical logic.